# How to Access the network path using C#

Tags: c#

my requirement is automatically save the file from data table using file stream when click the button from SharePoint site using C#. I tried to achieve this using below code. But it shows webpage declined to show this page error when click the button

byte[] txtFile = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

```
                mstxt.Write(txtFile, 0, txtFile.Length);
                mstxt.Position = 0;


                FileStream file = new FileStream(@"\\\\sapacpapp001v\\sapmnt\\transf\\in\\Currency\\Rates_SAP_" + dt + "_Eur.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                mstxt.WriteTo(file);
                file.Close();
```

Comment: what's the content of `row["Date"]`

Comment: post the content of row["Date"]

Comment: If `row` stores it as DateTime don't convert it to string to compare it with another DateTime. Cast it

Comment: It would certainly help us (and yourself) by adding what is found in `row["Date"]`.

Comment: Also, "code not working" is never a useful description. Be clear, always give details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the culture you are creating to converet the date. Try passing it in as a second parameter to ToDateTime rather than the ToString:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
 string sameDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"],ci).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Although The commenters above are correct, if the type of row["Date"] is a date time, then you don't need to convert it, just cast it. If it is a string, then you have to convert (but that is a horrible way to store a date in a database if you can use a date field.

Comment: Thank u Mikes for your valuable comment. I will check the above code in server